# there is filter box for searching in CGridView Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have used CGridView here is my code:-

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchsecond(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'#'),
        array('name'=>'sparktype_id', 'header'=>'First name'),
       array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

here is my output
[image]

here under firstname tab there is one textbox is there i want to add class to this.

here is the html for this textbox

```
<div class="filter-container">
<input type="text" name="Spark[sparktype_id]">
</div>
```

I want to add new class to this input tag.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
      'filterCssClass'=>'your Css class'
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchsecond(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'#'),
        array('name'=>'sparktype_id', 'header'=>'First name'),
       array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class that extends the `CDataColumn` class and put it for example in `extensions` folder.

dont forget add this folder to import section in `main.php` config

```
'import'=>array(
   ...
   'application.extensions.*',
   ...
)
```

In it, you must override `renderFilterCellContent` method.

```
class MyDataColumn extends CDataColumn{
        public function __construct($grid) {
            parent::__construct($grid);
        }

        protected function renderFilterCellContent()
        {
                if(is_string($this->filter))
                        echo $this->filter;
                elseif($this->filter!==false && $this->grid->filter!==null && $this->name!==null && strpos($this->name,'.')===false)
                {
                        if(is_array($this->filter))
                                echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($this->grid->filter, $this->name, $this->filter, array('id'=>false,'prompt'=>''));
                        elseif($this->filter===null)
                                echo CHtml::activeTextField($this->grid->filter, $this->name, array('id'=>false, 'class'=>'HereIsMyClassNameForFilterInput'));
                }
                else
                        parent::renderFilterCellContent();
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to:
`echo CHtml::activeTextField(..., ..., ..., 'class'=>'`**HereIsMyClassNameForFilterInput**`'));`

Also in the class `TbDataColumn` of bootstrap extension, you must change the name of the class that it extends.

```
class TbDataColumn extends MyDataColumn
{
...
```

if you want add different classes for every input you can:

- add property `public $filterClass = "";` to `MyDataColumn` class;
- change `echo CHtml::activeTextField($this->grid->filter, $this->name, array('id'=>false, 'class'=>'HereIsMyClassNameForFilterInput'));`

  to `echo CHtml::activeTextField($this->grid->filter, $this->name,
  array('id'=>false, 'class'=>$this->filterClass));`
- and in `column` section of `TbGridView` widget set value of` this variable:

  `'columns'=>array(
     ...
     array(
        'name'=>'name',
        'filterClass'=>'CustomClassForFilterInputInNameColumn'
     ),
     ...
  )`